# Microphone is very quiet even though its gain is maxed out in audio interface

Tags: audio, microphone

I use shure sv100 mic on my behringer um2 audio interface. It was working without any issue till the to date but now the mic is very quiet. It doesn't pick much of a sound unless you put it right at your mouth . It's not an issue with the mic as it is working fine on other devices.

I tried to reinstall update drivers for mic and audio interface but nothing changed..can someone help me?

Comment: Make sure you have the mic inserted in the mic in, not line in, and also make sure your soundcard does not have the mic in configured as line in. If this is correct, test the mic on another system to double check. if it fails there, the mic has a malfunction

Comment: Is there a chance your gain control knob may have come off at any point and then re-installed in the wrong position? So you think you're maxing it out but you're not?#